# How can I update specific value from MySQL JSON column

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to update a specific value in JSON array from a MySQL column by searching for specific `ID`, I want it to be dynamic without specifying array key.

Here is what I tried:

```
update myTable JSON_REPLACE(`data`, $.OD, '3/1')
where JSON_EXTRACT(`data`, '$.ID') = 'some id';
```

Here is my column data:

```
[
  {"ID":63010092,"IT":"OV80419947-63010092_1_3","OD":"21/10","SU":0,"OR":0},
  {"ID":63010093,"IT":"OV80419947-63010093_1_3","OD":"8/5","SU":0,"OR":1},
  {"ID":63010094,"IT":"OV80419947-63010094_1_3","OD":"8/5","SU":0,"OR":2}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (adjust everything you consider necessary):

```sql
UPDATE `myTable`
  INNER JOIN JSON_TABLE(
      `myTable`.`data`,
      '$[*]'
      COLUMNS(
        `position` FOR ORDINALITY,
        `ID` INT PATH '$.ID'
      )
    ) `der`
SET `data` = JSON_REPLACE(
  `myTable`.`data`,
  CONCAT('$[', `der`.`position` - 1, '].OD'),
  '3/1'
)
WHERE `der`.`ID` = 63010092;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aca18eda8dfafd258606428304eca794).